# Why this correct code in Golang is considered wrong at HackerRank?

Tags: algorithm, go

I solved "Compare the Triplets" in Golang using the following code, but its saying that the answer is wrong. 
When I run the code in my local environment it shows the desired results.

([here is the link to the problem at HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets))

Following is the code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := ReadArrays()
    sa, sb := CompareIt(a, b)
    fmt.Printf("A: %d, B: %d\n", sa, sb)
}

func CompareIt(a, b []int) (int, int) {
    var scoreA int
    var scoreB int

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        if a[i] > b[i] {
            scoreA += 1
        } else if b[i] > a[i] {
            scoreB += 1
        }
    }
    return scoreA, scoreB
}

func ReadArrays() ([]int, []int) {
    a := make([]int, 3)
    fmt.Println("Please enter the first 3 digits separated by space or comma")
    for i := range a {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[i])
    }
    b := make([]int, 3)
    fmt.Println("Please enter the second 3 digits separated by space or comma")
    for i := range b {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &b[i])
    }
    return a, b
}
```

When I run this code in my local environment, its asks me at the terminal to enter the first 3 digits, then its asks me to to insert the other 3 digits, then the code compare it and give the scores to A and B as required in the challenge.

Answer (score 7):

Your output does not match the expected output:

Your Output (stdout)

```
Please enter the first 3 digits separated by space or comma
Please enter the second 3 digits separated by space or comma
A: 1, B: 1
```

Expected Output

```
1 1
```

You are printing way more than they asked for. You are also making this program for a computer to run not a person. You don't need to have a text prompt.

Remove the excess printing:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := ReadArrays()
    sa, sb := CompareIt(a, b)
    fmt.Printf("%d %d", sa, sb)
}

func CompareIt(a, b []int) (int, int) {
    var scoreA int
    var scoreB int

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        if a[i] > b[i] {
            scoreA += 1
        } else if b[i] > a[i] {
            scoreB += 1
        }
    }
    return scoreA, scoreB
}

func ReadArrays() ([]int, []int) {
    a := make([]int, 3)
    for i := range a {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[i])
    }
    b := make([]int, 3)
    for i := range b {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &b[i])
    }
    return a, b
}
```